# need way to Reduce report

Tags: reporting, dashboard, report-builder

I have created  2 reports on account with same  filter criteria,but different group by 1 report group by Geography
2 report group by Indusrty.
and summarizing the annual revenue field for both report

Is there any way to combine these 2 reports to one.

Comment: Use joint reports to combine

Comment: no,but i want to reduce size of reports....alrady i have created 2 reports .Is join report reduces the report to 1